# Payment Processor Error

Tags: payment-processor

I am logged into our website, setting up a Contribution Page, and I need to set up a Payment Processor, but I am receiving and error message: ****The 'administer payment processors' permission is required to add or edit a payment processor.****

Answer (score 2):

Error seems to be self explanatory, You need to have `administer payment processors`  permission to Add, Update, or Disable Payment Processors.

If you're an admin, you can grant this permission by navigating to

Administer -> Users and Permission -> Permissions(Access Control)

and click on `Drupal/Joomla/Wordpress Access Control` w.r.t your CMS.